# perturbation inverse matrix power series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If ${\bf A}$ is an invertible matrix, then for ${\bf B}={\bf A}+\delta {\bf A}$
derive a representation of ${\bf B}^{-1}$ as a matrix power series in $\Delta={\bf A}^{-1}\delta{\bf A}$ 
and show that it converges when $\|\delta{\bf A}\|<\|{\bf A}^{-1}\|^{-1}$ for any proper matrix norm. 
State the necessary and sufficient condition on $\Delta$ for convergence of the series.

Any help is appreciated, I've been staring at this for quite a while

Comment: There is something called  a neumann series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write the real function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{a+x}$$
as a power series, then replace $a$ by the matrix $A$ and $x$ by the perturbation $\delta A$. Check that everything works for matrices.

**Warning:** Be careful, order of multiplication matters for matrices!